# Where does an upvote method belong in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The user clicks a button to upvote an Item. This should update @item.upvotes.

Where does this go? Here are the options I thought of. I'm not extremely familiar with the correct compartmentalization and I'm hoping to learn the reasoning behind this too.

1. Model -- as an instance method that updates immediately
2. Controller -- as a method that gets called using routing. If this is the case, why do we do this instead of making an instance method on the model?
3. Helper -- I'm not too familiar with what these do, but I know they can be called from the view. However, they seem to be better for things like string manipulation or working with stuff that belongs in the view.

Comment: To add a bit of clarification:
1 - As Pete says, the model is for validations and relations
2 - The controller is the glue between your views and models. It's here most of the functionality usually goes
3 - Helpers are there to help generating form elements afaik. E.g. form_for() is a helper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to have the upvote button (view) call a controller by routing to the correct method. Inside the controller method you tell the model to update the field. This is the MVC principle.

A model in Rails usually just holds validations, relations and the like. Updating a field is clearly a job for the controller.

I'm not that fluent with my ruby any more as I'm using java now but the controller should probably look something like this:

```
class ItemsController
  def upvote
    Items.increment_counter(:upvote, params[:id])
  end
```

In the view you have a button somewhere (via form or link_to) that posts the id to say a "/upvote" action:

```
<%= link_to "upvote", upvote_path(:id => @item.id) %>
```

In your routes file you send that to Items#upvote.

```
match "/upvote" => "items#upvote"
```

Comment: `@item.upvote = @item.upvote + 1` is a bad idea, the increment should take place entirely inside the database to avoid concurrency issues and AR even has methods to support such things.

Comment: I think you were looking for the [`increment_counter`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-increment_counter) method which does a direct UPDATE in the database and doesn't need to be followed by a `save` call.

Comment: I've been googling and it seems like `increment_counter` only works on counter caches, which the upvotes aren't. Should I be using Items.increment! instead?

Answer (score -2):

Check counter cache:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

Comment: Counter cache doesn't apply here. There is no `Vote` model and (therefore) no `belongs_to` relationship to add the counter cache to.